# Child write on file descriptors created in parent after fork

Tags: c++, unix, process, fork, file-descriptor

I have a parent process which listens for incoming connections on a socket and after accepting a client, It will pass the associated file descriptor and some other date to the child (through a named pipe).

From this moment on, child process will provide service to the client and the parent keeps listening for new clients.

My problem is that when I try to write on file descriptors in child process, I will get an error (Bad file descriptor) and write fails. My guess is that since these file descriptors are created after fork, child cannot simply use them and they only belong to the parent process.

So Is this the reason of write failure? Is there any possible way for child to use these file descriptors?

**Solution**

As it was mentioned in the answer by loreb, It is not possible to achieve the desired outcome in this manner. I did a temporary fix by using another pipe to direct the response from child to parent. Since file descriptors belong to parent, it can forward the response back to client through a socket.

Comment: why dont you create socket in parent process so that file descriptor will be shared between  parent and child..

Comment: @Abhiteshkhatri because my clients will continue to connect after the fork has taken place and file descriptors created after fork are not shared between parent and child.

Comment: you can create a shared memory before fork and keep file descriptors on shared memory (i have a doubt how to put file descriptors on shared memory). if so, then your descriptor will be shared between child and parent..

Comment: Unfortunately for this particular assignment we are not allowed to use shared memories and I have not dealt with storing file descriptors on shared memories before. So I am not sure if we can make use of shared memory here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a file descriptor you need to AF_UNIX sockets, not named pipes.
You'll need sendmsg(3), which is insanely weird to use, so you'd better look up some example on the web -- eg io_passfd in libowfat.

Edit: in case anyone stumbles upon this answer, don't use an AF_UNIX client/server, use socketpair(2)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So based on your answer, passing the file descriptor is not as simple as just passing the integer value to child. For this assignment I'm working on, it is not possible to use sendmsg() system call. I guess I have to do some redesigning here. Thanks again.

Comment: Right, it's not that simple; if you're interested in the details, there are some nice explanations in the "Related" section to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try closing and reopening of that FD.

Comment: The file descriptor belongs to a active socket connection so I guess it is not as simple as closing it in parent and reopening it in child.